# How long can Wonder Woman's Lasso of Truth grow?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

In all appearances (DCEU, DCAU and the comics), the lasso is shown to grown in size (maybe psychically by Diana) according to the need. Even as seen the latest iterations of Wonder Woman (Wonder Woman and WW84), we see her defending herself from Ares' attack (*Wonder Woman*) and swinging using the lasso that could be at least a few hundred meters long (*WW1984*).

[image: WW deflecting Ares' attacks using the Lasso (Wonder Woman)]

[image: WW swinging with her Lasso using a plane (Wonder Woman 1984)]

What is the maximum length that the lasso can grow up to? Is there any canonical explanation/instance where the maximum length that the Lasso of Truth is presented?

Comment: Very long indeed; https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6r1r.jpg

Comment: @Valorum Of course Batman's already compensated for what they're doing.  He probably had this scenario planned out a decade ago. :)

Comment: @Valorum lol that's ridiculous

Comment: @DKNguyen - Oh sure, because a magical lasso that makes people tell the truth is sensible story-telling, but having it be very long is nonsense.

Comment: @Valorum Well there's nonsense on a person-to-person scale, then there's nonsense on a person-to-planet scale lol

Answer (score 2):

### Like most comic creations, it varies.

Sometimes it has a maximum length of 150 feet. [Lasso of Truth](https://wonder-woman.fandom.com/wiki/Lasso_of_Truth#:%7E:text=The%20lasso%20is%20completely%20unbreakable,is%20approximately%20150%20feet%20long.), [15 Things You Didn't Know About The Lasso of Truth](https://screenrant.com/wonder-woman-lasso-of-truth-facts-trivia-history/)

Other times it is `exceptionally long and flexibility`. [Lasso of Truth](https://wonder-woman.fandom.com/wiki/Lasso_of_Truth#Justice_League) It's flexibility suggests it can lengthen even further as it flexes. Some bungie cords can stretch to twice their original length.

And as as [Valorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243186/how-long-can-wonder-womans-lasso-of-truth-grow#comment667575_243186) says, it was once imbued with a magic spell that made it long enough to net the entire Earth in order to drag it back into orbit.

Or maybe it could always do that.

> Thanks to Hephaestus’ Olympic construction of the holy rope, it can extend for a nearly infinite distance. Its only limitations are in the mind of its user, and wherever Diana Prince bids it to go, the Lasso of Truth will obey. - [15 Things You Didn't Know About The Lasso of Truth](https://screenrant.com/wonder-woman-lasso-of-truth-facts-trivia-history/)